# Drawing widget on touch down

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I need your help again, please. I am trying to create a simple menu (topMenu), that will update grid of buttons in Left (side of the center screen). Could you have a look below and advise, why nothing is drawn on the screen, despite of correct execution of the code in the background? (console log: Adding button: 0 - 24).

TopMenu.py:

```
import Categories
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
import Left

class TopMenu(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TopMenu, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("Top is alive!")

        self.drawBtns()

    # Get buttons from the category and draw them on the top screen
    def drawBtns(self):
        mainCats = Categories.Categories()
        for i in range(len(mainCats.mainCats)):
            but = MenuButton(mainCats.mainCats[i])
            self.add_widget(but)

# Custom class to create a button that contains all required parameters
class MenuButton(ToggleButton):
    def __init__(self, btnText, **kwargs):
        super(MenuButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.text = btnText
        self.group = "topMenuGroup"
        self.bind(on_press = self.topMenuPressed)

    ############################### FIRE EVENT IN THIS METHOD ############################
    def topMenuPressed(event, self):
        print("Pressed " + self.text + ":" + self.state)
        if self.state == "down":
            left = Left.Left()
            left.addBtns()
```

Left.py:

```
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Left(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Left, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("Left is alive!")
    ####################### DRAW BUTTONS TO THE GRID LAYOUT AND DISPLAY ON THE SCREEN #########
    def addBtns(self):
        for i in range(0, 25):
            print("Adding button: " + str(i))
            but = Button(text="X" + str(i) + "\n23." + str(i))
            self.add_widget(but)
```

I think my issue could be related with some screen refreshing? But I have no clue how to bite this :)

Comment: Did you add your layout to the screen so it can be shown?

Comment: Yes, I did, in KV file.<Center@GridLayout>:
    cols: 2
    size_hint: 1, 1
    Left:
        size_hint: 1,1
    Label:
        text: 'prawa'

Comment: Your code `left = Left.Left()` is creating a new instance of `Left` (not the one in your app display). So adding buttons to that new instance of `Left` will not affect the instance of `Left` in your display. You need to find a way to get a reference to the `Left` that is in your display. Possibly using `ids` (although that will be complex with your widget structure) or maybe putting your `addBtns()` method in a class that can more easily reference the `Left` instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@John Anderson, thank you for bringing me on the right track (again!). I did small research and come up with the idea below. It works just fine, but I am not sure if that is the best / most elegant way to solve this problem. Any suggestions will be most appreciated. For now I can move along with my project :-)

Left.py

```
class Left(GridLayout):
    leftInstances = [] # Store all instances of this class
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Left, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.__class__.leftInstances.append(self) # Add instance to instances list

    def drawBttns(self):
        for i in range(0, 25):
            but = Button(text="X" + str(i))
            self.add_widget(but)
```

and TopMenu.py:

```
    def topMenuPressed(event, self):
        print("Pressed " + self.text + ":" + self.state)
        print(Left.Left.leftInstances)
        Left.Left.leftInstances[0].drawBttns()
```

Comment: Clever approach. I think using `ids` would have been overly complex and obscure in this case.